# Why is a "leper" allowed to sit with other "lepers"?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tzaraas-negaim, parashat-tazria

In Parshat Tazria ([Vayikra 13:46](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15578&p=3&showrashi=true#v46)) we are told:

> All the days the lesion is upon him, he shall remain unclean. He is unclean; he shall dwell isolated; his dwelling shall be outside the camp

As Rashi explains:

> **He shall dwell isolated:** [meaning] that other unclean people [not stricken with tzara’ath] shall not abide with him.

*The source for the Judaica Press translation's parenthetical explanation of Rashi "people [not stricken with tzara’ath]" (implying that the leper may sit with other lepers) appears to be a Braitah brought in [Pesachim 67A and Rashi's commentary there](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=67&format=pdf).*

*The Talmud (according to Rashi) there explains that when the verse says "he shall dwell isolated" it means that other forms of impurity (Zav or one impure by a dead body) do not have to go outside all three camps, while the "leper" must.*

This seems to indicate that "lepers" may sit together, outside the camp. We see this in the story in [Melachim II 7:3](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b07.htm#3) as well, where there were 4 lepers sitting together at the gates of the city.

However Rashi on [Vayikra 13:46](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15578&p=3&showrashi=true#v46) continues.

> Our Sages said: “Why is he different from other unclean people, that he must remain isolated? Since, with his slander, he caused a separation [i.e., a rift] between man and wife or between man and his fellow, he too, shall be separated [from society].”- [Arachin 16b] [This rationale is based on the premise that a person is stricken with tzara’ath as a result of his talking לְשׁוֹן הָרַע, i.e., speaking derogatorily of others, although he may be telling the truth.]

If the "leper" must be isolated and separated from society due to the rifts he has caused, shouldn't he also be separated from other "lepers"? Why is he still allowed to sit with other "lepers"? Especially since the rifts Rashi (and [the Talmud](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=16b&format=pdf)) mention are personal rifts, not societal rifts. Why don't we say that just like he caused people to be separated, he too should be separated and alone?

Comment: I'm not sure sitting with three other lepers is considered in a society.

Comment: @DoubleAA: It's not, it's considered out of society. I'm just wondering why they shouldn't be isolated from each other as well. I'll try to edit the question to make it clearer

Comment: Maybe indeed it depends on whether the metzora in question was stricken with tzaraas because of lashon hara, or because of other sins (listed in Erchin 16a)?

Comment: Since they are punished for the same thing they will try to work on their mistakes together.

Comment: Maybe it's enough that the leper is separated from the rest of society. The Torah is merciful after all and realizes that a man cannot live entirely without society.

Comment: @avi I second [SethJ's remarks](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15948/why-is-a-person-with-tzaraath-allowed-to-sit-with-other-people-with-tzaraath#comment40746_17660) about matching transliteration scheme; consider how he transliterated "Parshat" and "Braitah". Also note how the word lepor was always in quotes implying an acknowledgment of the non-precise translation. I really have half a mind to rollback.

Comment: @DoubleAA: As you say, that's why I put leper in quotes. When it makes sense, I like to use english words (as opposed to transliterated words), since I figure that makes it easier to find the question on search engines. Especially since there are too many possible transliteration variations. If I would have gone for the hebrew word, I would have chosen "Metzorah".

Comment: @Menachem While we're on the topic of transliteration...מצורע ends with a closed syllable so I don't see why you would put a 'h' at the end of Metzorah.

Comment: @DoubleAA: rhymes with Chanukah :)

Comment: @Menachem :) Oh how Moshe would be so confused if he heard us speaking today.

Comment: @DoubleAA I just used the form used in the Wikipedia article, which acknlowedges no good english translation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzaraath  I figured if Wikipedia has an entry on it and doesn't give a strict english translation, then person with Tzaraath is the best way to go.

Comment: Leper should not even be in quotes.. there is NONE, ZERO relationship between Leporsy and Tzarath.  People should know what leporsy is before calling people with Tzarat "Lepers".   https://www.google.com/search?q=lepers&hl=en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=l0IAUOK2E4PbtAa1nMiPBg&ved=0CHAQsAQ&biw=1092&bih=499

Comment: Let me make myself clear. The problem is not with a bad translation of Tzaraat, my problem is with a complete lack of understanding what Leporsy is.  Lepers are not people with white skin blotches, they are people missing toes and fingers and noses.

Comment: @avi, a mathematician performs computations. Why don't you let the OP edit it the way he feels comfortable? It has the Tzaraas-Negaim tag, so people who feel the way you do and do internet searches will find it.

Comment: @avi, it's a common mistranslation, and it's the OP's. It's 100% incorrect, and please let it be unless the OP edits further.

Comment: @avi "Leprosy is a disease that has been known since biblical times. It causes skin sores, nerve damage, and muscle weakness that gets worse over time." [I guess NIH has no understanding of leprosy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0002323/).

Comment: @SethJ That is a good definition of Lepersy... NONE of those conditions exists on a Metzorah!!!!

Comment: @msh210 I will not allow obviously 100% incorrect information to be the basis of questions or answers on this site.

Comment: @Avi skin sores?

Comment: @SethJ  Do you know what skin sores are?  Pus, bloating, opening of the skin.  Nothing like Tazraat!  http://www.localhealth.com/article/sores

Comment: See: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47733&st=&pgnum=108

Answer (score 2):

[The Maayanah Shel Torah quotes the Ahavat Yehonatan](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41777&pgnum=85), who says that the lepers in Melachim II were actually suffering from natural leprosy, not Tzara'at.

If so, nothing can be proved from their case (at least according to the Ahavat Yehonatan). I suspect many commentaries disagree with this conclusion (including the one [quoted on the previous page](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41777&pgnum=84))

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry if you're not satisfied with this answer, but it's my honest feeling that when you untangle the disparate sources that you've quoted from one another, they're either not contradicting one another or it's not a problem that they do.

For a start, Rashi ([Leviticus 13:46](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/torahreading.asp?AID=15578&p=3&showrashi=true#v46)) never says that people afflicted with any other type of impurity may not dwell with the leper, but simply other impure people. He doesn't say which, though I would imagine that he is speaking specifically of somebody with an emission and somebody with corpse impurity. The parenthetical section that you included in your translation was composed by whomever is responsible for the translation at chabad.org (The Judaica Press). Read it in the Hebrew alongside and you'll see that it says no such thing:

> שלא יהיו שאר טמאים יושבים עמו
>
> That other impure people should not dwell with him.

Secondly, Rashi is quoting two completely different sources, and the fact that there appears to be a contradiction between them is not a problem with those sources but a question on Rashi's methodology in particular. You can see the same apparent "contradiction" in Rashi's observations on [2 Kings 7:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14263&pgnum=287). First he brings a gemara from Sanhedrin that posits that the four lepers are Gehazi and his sons, and then he quotes the passage from Leviticus 13, which emphasizes that the leper dwells "alone" (בדד).

So far as those two sources are concerned, the first is a beraita that is brought down in [Pesachim 67a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=4&daf=67&format=pdf) in the name of Rabbi Yochanan. The beraita appears to be based on a passage in Sifra (§13, 157.12), on which the Malbim writes that it is only from those who've had an emission (the *zav*) and from those with corpse impurity that the *metzora'* needs to distance himself. His reading of the Sifra (and of the beraita in Pesachim and its parallel in [Zevachim 117a)](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=29&daf=117&format=pdf) is that people with *tzara'at* can spend time with other people who also have *tzara'at*, and even other people with different kinds of impurity - so long as they are not of the two varieties I just mentioned. In that sense, the Malbim is saying something different to Rashi, whose mention of the *zav* and the *tamei met* in Pesachim 67a is preceded by כגון ("*for example*" - ie: not exclusively).

The second source, which Rashi presents as the "reason" for the *metzora'* dwelling apart is from a beraita that's brought down in [Arakhin 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=33&daf=16b&format=pdf) in the name of Rabbi Hanina. Are you trying to indicate a 'contradiction' between Rabbi Hanina and Rabbi Yochanan, or are you asking how it is that Rashi could possibly combine the two responses?

If it's the latter, then your question is effectively: "How do I reconcile Rashi's commentary on Pesachim 67a with his commentary on Leviticus 13:46?" I think that anybody will tell you that Rashi's gemara commentary is his attempt at explaining the gemara (in this case, trying to understand Rabbi Yochanan's reasoning), and not a reflection of his halakha. That's why there are so many contradictions (as there are in the gemara itself) and why what he writes doesn't always match what's found in his *piskei dinim*.

Comment: I suggest replacing all instances of "leper" with "people with tzaraath"

Comment: @avi, I'm commenting here so you can see my constructive criticism, even though it relates to your edit on the question. First, I disagree that "leper" is not a valid English rendition, even if it is not a correct translation, since the vast majority of the English speaking world equates the two, and someone searching the internet will likely find the question that way. Second, if you are going to edit someone else's language, I recommend that if you cannot be certain how they would transliterate a Hebrew word into English, you use a more neutral and widely accepted transliteration scheme.

Comment: Kings 2 7:3 is not a contradiction in Rashi, since even if they weren't Gechazi and his sons, there would still be 4 men sitting together. Rather, it is Rashi interpreting "alone" as "able to be with others suffering from the same ailment".

Comment: My question is "why can lepers sit with other lepers, if they are supposed to be isolated due to the nature of their transgression". I agree that Rashi himself only says "other impure", which could mean "other impure people" or "other types of impurity". The Gemara he is quoting says explicitly "other types of impurity". While there is no proof that that is what Rashi is means as well, if you want to tell me that Rashi is interpreting the verse in a different manner than the Talmud's interpretation, I'd like some proof.

Comment: @avi That was actually my mistake. I thought I'd changed every instance of "leper" to "metzora'", but because I moved paragraphs around I ended up missing three. That said, while "leprosy" is not a translation of "tzara'at", leprosy was most certainly a type of tzara'at, so I don't think it's that bad a mistake. Feel free to change it if you think it needs to be changed.

Comment: @Menachem Yeah, I didn't think you'd like it :) It was kind of a non-answer - just me suggesting why I don't see that there's a question here. It was too long for a comment, so I put it in the answers box instead. I think that what you're asking can be asked about any type of impurity, to be honest, and am open to hearing explanations. (PS: When you say "the Talmud's interpretation", I think that what you mean to say is "Rabbi Yochanan's interpretation.)

Comment: @Menachem One more thing, just for future reference. I have no problem with people editing my answers (obviously) and either adding or removing information, but if you want to correct my spelling, please note that I am from Australia! "Emphasise" is a perfectly legitimate spelling of the the word! "Apparant" is not, and I thank you for fixing that one :)

Comment: @ShimonbM: My bad, I looked at the firefox squiggly red line, and just made the correction. I wasn't thinking globally.

Comment: @SethJ I actually didn't edit the answer at all.  However I used the transliteration used by the Wiki article on the topic.  I figured that would be the most common usage.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tzaraath

Comment: @ShimonbM Lepersy is NOT a form of Tzarath. There is no form of leporsy in the world that matches the description of Tzarat, and they are completely different things.  This was an error from the 1800s and should be erraticated http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprosy.

Comment: @avi ... and American Indians have nothing to do with India. Nonetheless, unfortunate as it may be, both "leper" and "Indian" have taken on second meanings through hundreds of years of use. If Menachem chooses to revert back to using his original terminology, please leave it that way.

Comment: @IssacMoses The meaning of Leper has not changed.  People think the Bible is talking about people who's limbs fall off.

Comment: @avi: Anybody who thinks that the Bible is talking about people whose limbs fall off doesn't know anything about the Bible. Conversely, anybody who thinks that lepers are people whose limbs fall off doesn't know anything about leprosy. Fact: there were lepers in ancient Israel. This has been scientifically determined on the basis of DNA analysis and has never been disputed by anybody. Perhaps the Israelites were the only people in the ancient world not to quarantine lepers? Or perhaps it was simply a type of tzaraat, together with a dozen other known conditions, from psoriasis to dry rot.

Comment: @ShimonbM That leporsy existed is true. That lepersy was in anyway related to Tzaraat is 100% NOT true.

Answer (score 1):

@ba, in [his comment on the question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15948/why-is-a-leper-allowed-to-sit-with-other-lepers#comment51878_15948),  linked to [chapter 47 of "Gam Ani Odecha" by Gamliel HaKohen Rabinovitch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47733&st=&pgnum=108). There, he collects responses he received from several contemporary halachic authorities regarding whether a Metzorah must sit alone.

In short (and I may be glossing over some important details, so please read it inside), there are authorities that appear to say yes, and those that appear to say no.

The basic distinction seems to be whether the Metzorah must sit alone because of impurity, or because he is considered as one who is excommunicated. If he must only be alone because of impurity, others may join him, if they wish. Whereas if he must be alone because it is like he is excommunicated, no one else may join him.

[There is some discussion about whether his wife may join him, and passing mention to his children, but none of the responses mentions the 4 "lepers" sitting at the gate.]

---

Note that this is not discussing the rationale of *"Since...he caused a separation ...between man and wife or between man and his fellow, he too, shall be separated
..."*