# Traditions what to do with removed foreskin

Tags: minhag, brit-milah, parts-of-the-body, funeral-burial-levaya

In Germany we recently started a debate, whether foreskin-amputation of children (not only Jews, but Muslims as well) has to be forbidden according to our fundamental laws.

Some magazine illustrated their article with a big glass which contained foreskins, but I can't find it again. From my impression, it looked like something from a museum and I associate it with Jewish, not Muslim tradition.

So my question is: Is there a tradition to collect the foreskin? I think I read that the Mohel takes his foreskins into the grave. Is this true (maybe only in some regions)? If so - does anybody have a link to such an image?

(rejected tags: foreskin circumcision mohel tradition)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

after the circumcision, the foreskin is buried (some prepare a dish with dirt in it to "bury" the foreskin immediately). Some bury it in earth that has a new tree planted in it as a symbolic connection but the operative point is respect and burial for the body part.

cf [Do surgically removed body parts require Kevurah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9909/do-surgically-removed-body-parts-require-kevurah)

the comments on the question which refer to the code of Jewish law [stating](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9147&st=&pgnum=174) that the foreskin must be covered in sand and dirt.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7924&st=&pgnum=190