# May a Kohen bury limbs of his 7 krovim (first degree relatives) which were removed during their lifetime?

Tags: halacha-theory, kohen-priest, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

According to the opinion that [limbs removed from a live person](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9909/do-surgically-removed-body-parts-require-kevurah) [should be buried](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=t_g7H2olIBUC&pg=PA292&lpg=PA292&dq=amputation%20tumah&source=bl&ots=WueOUBK-L7&sig=SfTTjEhvZEVUIRgCIHIInn74Tlw&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=amputation%20tumah&f=false), may a Kohen bury limbs of his 7 krovim [first degree relatives) which were removed during their lifetime?

Answer (score 7):

[YD 373:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.373.9)

> אין הכהן מיטמא לאבר מן החי מאביו, ולא לעצם מעצמות אביו. וכן המלקט
> עצמות אינו מיטמא להם אע"פ שהשדרה קיימת.
>
> חסר ממנו כל שהוא -- אפי' הוא מונח אצלו -- אינו מיטמא לו; שאינו מיטמא
> אלא לשלם.
>
> ויש מי שאומר דהני מילי כשחסר לאחר מיתה אבל אם חסר ממנו אבר בחייו ומת
> -- מיטמא לו אע"פ שאינו שלם. *(וי"א שאינו מיטמא להרוג דמקרי חסר) (ונכון להחמיר).*
>
> The Kohen does not defile himself for a limb [severed] from his father while [the latter] was still alive, nor for a bone of his father's bones. And so too, he who collects bones, — [the law is that] he does not defile himself for them, although the spinal column is intact.
>
> [If] a small part is missing, even if it lies beside him [the corpse], he does not defile himself for him, for he defiles himself only when he is whole.
>
> And there is one [authority] who says that this applies only if he [the corpse becomes] defective after death, but if there is a limb missing from him during his lifetime, and [then] he died, — he defiles himself for him [the corpse], although he is not whole. *And some say that he does not defile himself for a slain person, for he [the slain person] is designated defective. And it is proper to adopt the stringent view.*