# Burying/saving body parts of people who are still alive

Tags: halacha, army-military-war, funeral-burial-levaya

Unfortunately, post 7 October 2023, I have seen the scenario a number of times. If a person has a part of their body removed (e.g., during a battle) does that body part need to be immediately buried? Or not even buried at all?

I have anecdotally heard that some keep the body part for later burial, or bury it immediately and later re-bury the body part with the person after he/she dies, etc. What are the halachic opinions on the matter?

Comment: Duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9909/759

Comment: @DoubleAA thanks +1. i additionally want to know if the body part should be "re-united" when the person dies. I had heard this anecdotally.